# JPA ManyToMany mappedBy clarification

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm learning to use JPA and there's one thing that confuses me. I'm trying to implement a many to many relationship between two classes that I've got. My database schema is simple enough. There's one table called *stations (PK: station_id)*, one called *buses (PK: bus_id)* and one to connect them up together called *station_bus (FKs: station_id, bus_id)*.

The relevant code:

```
// Station Class
@Entity
@Table(name = "stations")
public class Station {
    private List<Bus> buses;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "station_bus",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "bus_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "station_id")}
    )
    public List<Bus> getBuses() { return buses; }
}

// Bus Class
@Entity
@Table(name = "buses")
public class Bus {
    private List<Station> stations;

    @ManyToMany(
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            mappedBy = "buses"
    )
    public List<Station> getStations() { return stations; }
}
```

There is one thing that confuses me. I understand that in a many to many relationship, one needs to be the owner, Station in this case, and one the ownee. The difference being the owner needs to specify the `@JoinTable` annotation and the ownee needing to specify `mappedBy`. The thing I don't understand is what the `mappedBy` value needs to be set to.

From what I gather from the various examples I've looked over is that it needs to be the name of the field in the owner class, so in this example, since Station contains a buses field, that's what the mapped by needs to be set to.

If anybody could confirm or correct me, it would be helpful, as I haven't been able to find an answer.

Comment: I think you are right - it is the name of the field on the other side of the relation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some notes:

> The absence of the mappedBy element in the mapping annotation implies
>   ownership of the relationship, while the presence of the mappedBy
>   element means the entity is on the inverse side of the relationship.
>
> The value of `mappedBy` is the name of the attribute in the owning
>   entity that points back to the inverse entity.

Your sample use of mappedBy is correct.